# Take variable name as a string inside list in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way i can take variable name inside a list to string?

for example:

```
abc, def, ghi, jkl = (1,2,3,4)
arr = [abc, def, ghi, jkl]
```

i need to create a list for every variable name, so i can get:

```
arr_name = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

i need to do this so i don't have to type every variable name for labels in pie plot. Or is creating `dict` the best way for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you expand on why you need to do this? I think there might be other (most natural) solutions if you ask the bigger problem you are trying to resolve here.

Comment: You don't want to do that, trust me.

Comment: That would be hard to do. The list in `arr` has no memory of where its objects came from. You could potentially scan all of the variables in the namespace and find those that have the same object as the items in the list. That would shorten the list. But if `foo` happened to also be `1`, you wouldn't know whether the first item in the list came from `foo` or `abc`.

Comment: There are other data structures that may work better. With a `dict`, you could keep a name/value association `{"abc":1, "def":2}`.

Comment: Okay, if you're really want to do that (but you don't, check prev comment), you have to take a look on [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

Comment: First, `def` is a reserved word in Python. You cannot have a variable named `def`

Comment: The way you have done it in the question is the best way to do it, just manually put `''` around the variable names. There is no scenario where you would need this to be done dynamically.

Comment: `arr_name = [i for i in globals()]` will get you an array of those var names and whatever others are in `globals()`.  If your code is simple, that might be usable.

Comment: @GAEfan, `list(globals())` will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

```
var_dict = {}

var_dict["abc"], var_dict["def"], var_dict["ghi"], var_dict["jkl"] = (1,2,3,4)
arr = list(var_dict)

print(arr)
#['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

Comment: Why do you initialize dict in such a weird way?

Comment: `list(var_dict.keys())` => `list(var_dict)` keys is not needed

Comment: @Olvin Roght What would be an appropriate way? dict() ? If so why is that better?

Comment: Common ways are: `var_dict = {"abc": 1, "def": 2, "ghi": 3, "jkl": 4}` or `var_dict = dict(("abc", 1), ("def", 2), ("ghi", 3), ("jkl", 4))`.

Comment: @Olvin Roght ahhh! I thought you mean the var_dict = {}. I simply tried to be as close to the question as i could. I would have initialized it differntly aswell.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre♦  You are right, I wasn't actually aware of that. Is there a downside to use .keys()? Because I think it makes it more explicit and easier to understand, but might as well be just my taste.

Comment: there's a downside in python 2 (because it creates a copy already), and calling one more method is slower

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre♦  ahhhh, thank you very much for the explaination.